# Using BLE in android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I need some guidance on a project im currently working on - I work on a project to communicate with a BLE device s.t. the device is connected to an android phone and transmits some data once in a while. I saw some lectures on BLE communication with android devices and read some information on the android 4.3 bluetooth API but there are some things I didnt got yet

1. In case I want my app to be compitable backward (up to 2.3) is that possible? did they (Google) include the new features on the support package?
2. Where can I find some good code example of using the android as a client?
3. When communicating with an android device I need the charestirestic of the bluetooth device to have UUID, do I generate some UUID's on the run? (and in that case how) or do I hard-code them on the app? (since on that case two people using this app and close to each other basically can read each other's signal, don't they?)

Answer (score 3):

> In case I want my app to be compitable backward (up to 2.3) is that possible? did they (google) include the new features on the support package?

Bluetooth low energy needs to be supported by the HW and there are only a handful of devices with the necessary Bluetooth radio running an older version of Android. For sure no device running 2.3 will be able to run BLE.

> Where can I find some good code example of using the android as a client?

The examples provided on [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) is actually quite good

> When communicating with an android device I need the charestirestic of the bluetooth device to have UUID, do I generate some UUID's on the run?

Bluetooth Special Interest Group has already created a bunch of [assigned numbers](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers). These have a well defined meaning across all BLE devices and services. Then businesses can apply for a range of UUID's that they can use to defined there own services.

On top of that there are some free ranges where everyone can define and use UUID's. These will not be well defined across devices, meaning other applications will not understand the UUID's you've defined.

Comment: In fact, BLE in Android is just available after Android 4.3 (API Level 18) http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: @GoRoS: The official Android API has only been available since 4.3. At least HTC and Samsung had their own proprietary API'es some time before that.

Comment: There is an open source BLE example which support Android 4.2(Broadcom, Samsung SDK) and Android 4.3+ in github: https://github.com/xpg/GizwitsBLE, hope this will help.